# Flot chart zoom generates unnecessary long y axis decimal values

Tags: jquery, angularjs, flot

Whenever I zoom the flot chart too much, it creates extremely large Y Axis value.

e.g.

I zoom in on 15, instead of showing `15.2, 15.4, 15.6`, it shows `15.2000000001, 15.40000000001`, etc.

I dont want to limit the decimal size, as I need flexibility in data. So when the data is 17.12345 I need to show it. But how do I fix this .00000001 thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `tickFormatter` function for the axis like this:

In your options add

```
yaxis: {
    tickFormatter: roundTicks,
    ...
}
```

And the function itself

```
function roundTicks(value, axis) {
    return Math.round(value * 1000000000) / 1000000000;
}
```